# window.onload function is not getting called on the page

Tags: javascript, html

My code is as shown below:

xyz.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Status</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 300px;padding: 10px;margin: 0 auto;background: #f2f2f2;">
    <form name="Form">
      <input type="hidden" name="Status" value="<?php echo $_POST['Status'] ?>" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert(window.onload);
      window.onload = function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://api.com');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var apiresponse = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            console.log(apiresponse);
            if (apiresponse.status == "200") {
              document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = apiresponse.message + '<br/> Press back button to continue in App.';
            } else {
              document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(apiresponse);
            }
          } else {
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(xhr);
          }
        };
        var elements = document.forms['Form'].elements;
        let formBody = [];
        for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
          let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(element.name);
          let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(element.value);
          formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
        }
        formBody = formBody.join("&");
        document.getElementById('request').innerHTML = formBody;
        xhr.send(formBody);
      }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

when I run the above code, in `alert` method I get `null` value and the function below it given with `window.onload = function()` is not getting called at all. So is there anything which needs to be included to get it done.

Comment: _"in alert method i get null"_ as expected, because `window.onload` has no value at that moment. Why do you think that the `onload` handler isn't executed? Any errors in the console? Check the network tab for the request (and the possible response).

Comment: in console tab it is giving me error `(index):79 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at window.onload ((index):79)`

Comment: You are trying to set the `innerHTML` properties of elements with ids `request` and `response`, but there are no elements with those ids. Thats an error. The browser is **much** better at debugging than we are.

Comment: See, the browser did already tell you the exact problem ;)

Comment: thanks , with the help of that , i could fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

When you call `alert(window.onload)` it is null because you have not assigned a function to `window.onload`. Your `alert` proves nothing.

For a sanity check, add the code `alert('hello world');` above the line `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` in the `function` you bind to `window.onload`. You will probably find that your function is being called but its behavior is not acting as you expect, so you think your function is NOT being called on `window.onload` but it actually is.